# Join SQL Server and Oracle Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I need a help on `SSIS.`

I have a table called `Orders` with millions of `records`. It have a column called `OrderID`. This is in `SQL Server.`

I have a similar table called `Orders` with again millions of rows and same column called `OrderID`. This is in `Oracle Server`

Now I need to pass `OrderID` from SQL Server and check the `OrderID` exists in Oracle Server.

I tried `Lookup` and `Merge Join`. Both were deadly slow.

Any help on Quickly perform a join if `OrderID` found then `set = Found` else `NotFound.`

Please help me out

Comment: which provider you are using to connect the oracle data source? Are you doing any data-conversions while fetching data? could you provide any screenshot of your ssis design?

Comment: Since I cannot comment yet so will drop a solution with assumptions that you can stop using SSIS without issues. So instead os SSIS, you could use Linked server to bring data from Oracle database table over to a staging table in SQL server. Later you can compare in TSQL between these 2 tables.